# Unique IDs based on First datetime

Tags: sql, database, datetime, unique

I am trying to figure out how to run a SQL query to only show unique users (CUSTOMER_ID) with the earliest datetime stamp (FBPOINTSDTS). I have looked into using DISTINCT, but haven't been able to make it work.

Here is my sample table:

```
ID              |CUSTOMER_ID     |REFERENCE_ID    |FBPOINTSDTS
VA00001000001336|CU00001000001173|RC00001000265536|10/28/2014 18:27
VA00001000000221|CU00001000001440|RC00001000249871|06/20/2014 14:10
VA00001000000249|CU00001000001440|RC00001000250058|06/21/2014 13:23
VA00001000001332|CU00001000001472|RC00001000265527|10/28/2014 17:01
VA00002000000434|CU00001000001637|RC00002000428796|10/28/2014 15:57
VA00001000000145|CU00001000001866|RC00001000248169|06/07/2014 12:04
VA00001000000343|CU00001000001866|RC00001000251616|07/07/2014 10:35
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (mysql, sql server, oracle...) as your answer may be depend on a specific implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select customer_id, min(FBPOINTSDTS) from [your table] group by customer_id;
```

This query will show you unique CUSTOMER_IDs and their minimum FBPOINTSDTS.